# adding an action to a hook in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to add an action that will add the price per unit to products in my woocommerce store. I've added the following code to functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_price_per_unit', 23);

function add_price_per_unit(){
?>
    <span class="pricePerGramArchive">
                <?php 
                if (get_field('display_price_per_unit')) {
                    $price = $product->get_price();
                    $unit = get_field('unit');
                    $unit_value = get_field('unit_value');
                    $price_per_unit = $price / $unit_value;
                    $price_per_unit_round = round($price_per_unit, 2);
                    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                    echo $unit_value.$unit." (".$price_per_unit_round." ".$currency_symbol."/".$unit.")";
                } ?>
    </span>
<?php

return $unit_value.$unit." (".$price_per_unit_round." ".$currency_symbol."/".$unit.")";

}
```

On the front end, I can see the span "pricePerGramArchive" showing up, but it's empty, and the formatting of my products gets messed up - products show up full width, and only one, instead of 11 products are shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$product` is not empty? If not try this:

```
if (get_field('display_price_per_unit', $product->get_id())) {
   // Change price here..
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried your version, but I'm getting the same result as before. Here's a link, so you can see what I mean: http://46.101.171.246/shop-en/?lang=en

Comment: I think you got some error, did you have enabled wp_debug in the `wp-config.php`? Because inside the span you see a W3 total cache message. It looks like you have some syntax error and the footer is closed earlier than normally